# Frame grabbing from camera using commandline

Tags: 14.04

I need to grab frames from the USB interfaced camera. 
Please let me know what tools can be used to capture video without GUI but only by using the commands in the terminal in Ubuntu 14.04.

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

install `fswebcam`:

> Fswebcam is a tiny and flexible webcam command-line program for
>   capturing  images from a V4L1/V4L2 device. It accepts a number of
>   formats, can skip  the first (possibly bad) frames before performing
>   the actual capture, and  can perform simple manipulation on the
>   captured image, such as resizing,  averaging multiple frames or
>   overlaying a caption or an image.

Comment: Thank you for the response! :) I wish to capture video in raw format and not in any encoded formats. Please let me know how I can do that.. I am using an embedded board which gives pixelated videos in encoded format. I wish to have better quality videos as I am supposed to process it further..